# Browser not passing Cookies to IFrame

Tags: asp.net, cookies, iframe, widget

I am testing a sample widget in my asp.net application. The application sets a cookie called "User" after a successful login.

```
var Opt = new CookieOptions() { SameSite=SameSiteMode.Lax};
Response.Cookies.Append("User", Input.Email, Opt);
```

The Widget pages:
Index.cshtml.cs:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public void OnGet()
        {
            var User = Request.Cookies["User"];
            ViewData["User"] = User;
        }
    }
```

Index.cshtml page:

```
    @page
    @model Frictionless.Areas.Widget.Pages.IndexModel
    @{
    }
    <div>
        <h4>Iframe Content</h4>
        <p id="#User">User=@ViewData["User"]</p>
    </div>
```

When I directly access the page: https://localhost:44358/Widget, It correctly shows the User ID.
My test HTML that includes iframe from the same page looks like this:

```
<HTML>
<body>
    <div>
        <p>This the main page</p>
    </div>
    <iframe id="FL" src="https://localhost:44358/Widget"></iframe>
</body>
</HTML>
```

This page shows User=empty. On chrome browser I can clearly see that the cookie is set for this domain, so looks like the browser is for some reason not passing the cookie to the iframe source get.
[browser page showing iframe and the cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5qSr.png)

I tried various cookie options (httponly, secure, samesite:none, etc.), but none of them helped.